# Filter an array based on object different values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to simplify an array of objects filtering. Let's assume that I have following array,

```
const users = [{
    name: "user1",
    gender: "m"
  }, {
    name: "user2",
    gender: "f"
  }, {
    name: "user3",
    gender: "f"
  }, {
    name: "user4",
    gender: "m"
  }, {
    name: "user5",
    gender: "m"
  }];
```

For example i need to filter all users by male or female, so i do loop through filter object property:

```
const fUsers = users.filter(user => user.gender === "f");
const mUsers = users.filter(user => user.gender === "m");

const results = [fUsers, mUsers];
console.log(results);
```

Is there any better way to filter to do it in one shot, so i can get results in mutiple arrays.

Comment: you could use reduce to output an array with two arrays of filtered content.

Answer (score 4):

You can use reduce function and in the accumulator pass a nested array. In the callback check the gender and you can use `acc[0]` to add elements in the first nested array of the accumulator or `acc[1]`

```js
const users = [{
  name: "user1",
  gender: "m"
}, {
  name: "user2",
  gender: "f"
}, {
  name: "user3",
  gender: "f"
}, {
  name: "user4",
  gender: "m"
}, {
  name: "user5",
  gender: "m"
}];

const newArr = users.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.gender === 'f') {
    acc[0].push(curr)
  } else {
    acc[1].push(curr)
  }
  return acc;
}, [
  [],
  []
]);

console.log(newArr)
```

Alternatively you can also use normal for loop

```js
const users = [{
  name: "user1",
  gender: "m"
}, {
  name: "user2",
  gender: "f"
}, {
  name: "user3",
  gender: "f"
}, {
  name: "user4",
  gender: "m"
}, {
  name: "user5",
  gender: "m"
}];

let arr = [
  [],
  []
];
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  users[i].gender === 'f' ? arr[0].push(users[i]) : arr[1].push(users[i])
};

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: ternary operators are perfect for this, and reduce line count.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `Array.reduce`.

On `Array.reduce` callback, if gender is `m`, you can `push` to `acc[0]` and if `gender` is `f`, you can `push` to `acc[1]`.

```js
const users = [{
  name: "user1",
  gender: "m"
}, {
  name: "user2",
  gender: "f"
}, {
  name: "user3",
  gender: "f"
}, {
  name: "user4",
  gender: "m"
}, {
  name: "user5",
  gender: "m"
}];

const result = users.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  cur.gender === 'f' ? acc[0].push(cur) : acc[1].push(cur);
  return acc;
}, [ [], [] ]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Basic approach

### forEach

Basically for any kind of operation with array, you can use a `forEach`.In this case you just create as much help variables as you neeed and process filter logic in `forEach`.

```
const males = []
const females = []
users.forEach(u=> u.gender === 'm' ? males.push(u) : females.push(u))
```

### Another javascript Loop

Another simple solution is to use one of javascript [loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp), in my example I have chosen `for-in` but principle is the same as in `forEach` example

```
const males = []
const females = []
for (u in users) {
    if (u.gender === 'm') {
        males.push(u)
    } else { 
        females.push(u)
    }
}
```

## Advanced approach

### reduce

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is function which allows as to process array loop and store result to single variable called accumulator, which is shared in every loop step. We can use `[[],[]]` => array of arrays accumulator

```
const [males, females] = users.reduce((acc, user) => {
      if (user.gender === 'm') {
        acc[0].push(u)
      } else {
        acc[1].push(u)
      }
      return acc;
    }, [[], []])
```

#### reduce one-liner

Same principle as the last, but refactored to one line. (not the beast readability)

```
const [males, females] = users.reduce((acc, u) => (u.gender === 'm' ? acc[0].push(u) : acc[1].push(u), acc), [[],[]])
```

### lodash/underscore

If you use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy), you can use a groupBy function, which create object with keys consist of filter attributes and array values, same function you can find also in [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#groupBy).

```
const result = _.groupBy(users, 'gender'));
// { 'm': [{male1, male2}], 'f': [female1, female2] }
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work, instead of two filters, you can reduce into an array of two arrays, sorting as you go. the acc is set after the function that reduce uses.

```
const sortedByGender =users.reduce((acc, user)=>{
  user.gender==="f"?acc[0].push(user):acc[1].push(user);
  return acc;
},[[],[]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group by gender and take a destructuring with a renaming to the wanted variable names.

```js
const
    users = [{ name: "user1", gender: "m" }, { name: "user2", gender: "f" }, { name: "user3", gender: "f" }, { name: "user4", gender: "m" }, { name: "user5", gender: "m" }],
    { f: fUsers, m: mUsers } = users.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.gender] ??= []).push(o), r), {});

console.log(fUsers);
console.log(mUsers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```